# How can I update the table while deleting the value in search bar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm able to search the table matching the values in my search bar but the state is not updating while deleting the value.
Here's my sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-lake-u1lcr)

Comment: Hi, your sandbox is not complete. Nothing is getting rendered.

Comment: Can you try this link? https://codesandbox.io/s/green-lake-u1lcr-u1lcr

Comment: Still doesn't render. Your data component you created is not being called in your app.js. Probably haven't sent the updated version?

Comment: I've got it to work... https://codesandbox.io/s/green-lake-u1lcr-7ln1n

Comment: but something is missing, you have no onchange event on your search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search input should use a similar onChange handler.

Your initial data shouldn't be directly set in your `useState`, seperate it into a new file called (i.e.:) `data.js` and import it as `data`.

Then on input change, simply filter through the data and choose which ever row matches best.

```
  const handleSearchChange = e => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = e;
    if (!!value) {
      const filteredData = data.filter(row => {
        return Object.values(row)
          .join(" ")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(value.toLowerCase());
      });
      setIsAll(filteredData);
    } else {
      setIsAll(data);
    }
  };
```

[sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/green-lake-u1lcr-7ln1n)

Comment: Hi. Can I still make this work even if my data is populated through API?

Comment: @AlyssaReyes of course. You can get the `data` from your parent's component `componentDidMount` (via fetch), update the state, and pass the data to your component as a prop... then use it like I did.

Comment: I'm using useEffect since I'm using hooks. In my sample I have there my API fetch. Not sure why I can't make it work in my code :(

Comment: @AlyssaReyes I just checked and the problem is because of CORS. Would appear that the server hosting your mock data has not allowed for cross origin to be used. I'd recommend using a different api provider.

Comment: Actually I'm using it on my local server and it's working. It's populating in the table. I'll try to update it using the structure of my code

Comment: By the way, why are you using this code ```(!!value)```

Comment: @AlyssaReyes a habit when I want to force convert it to a boolean. Though, it's not needed in this case.

Comment: @AlyssaReyes if it's working then try this ... https://owq39.csb.app/

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-lake-u1lcr-3bphc Here's my updated file with API integrated. the ```(!!value)``` is not working in my local though

Comment: I think it's working because I still have the data.js file that my search function is filtering. Do I need to have a temp variable for all the data from my api?

Comment: @AlyssaReyes well I fixed your problem : https://4yu4b.csb.app/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202099/discussion-between-alyssa-reyes-and-kemicofa).